# Why can't I install modules using pip

Tags: python, pip

I can't install any module. For example, the command

```
pip install Pillow
```

gives the following error

```
Collecting Pillow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pillow
```

I have a mac with two operating systems. One is macOS Sierra and the other is Linux Mint. Both give exactly the same error.

Comment: In linux use `sudo pip install Pillow`

Comment: "I can't install any module".. does this mean you get the same error trying to install anything? what happens when you try to `pip install django` or `pip install flask`

Comment: Try `pip install --user Pillow`

Comment: Do not follow @arsho's advice. `sudo pip install`  can potentially lead to hard to diagnose and/or repair configurations, unless you are in a virtual environment.

Comment: What are the versions of Python and pip? `python --version` and `pip --version`

Comment: I think its just `pip install pillow`

Comment: maybe try pip3 install pillow?